# Spacewalk client SSL certificate error

Tags: centos, redhat

I installed spacewalk 2.7 on CentOS, Create a configuration channel and able to register client into a channel however, When I tried to pull/diff a file it fails with ssl certificate error.

[root@eagles ~]# rhncfg-client diff
Using server name spacewalk.test.com
XML-RPC error while talking to https://spvstest.test.local/CONFIG-MANAGEMENT: [('SSL routines', 'ssl3_get_server_certificate', 'certificate verify failed')]
[root@eagles ~]#

I tried to install a new certificate with the link below but no luck
https://access.redhat.com/solutions/15753

How do I fix this certificate error.

Regards
Arjun

Comment: I am able to fix the issue. I changed from "https" to "http"  in rhncfg-client.conf in the client node. server_url = http://%(server_name)s%(server_handler)s

Comment: That doesn't fix the issue, rather just avoids it. You need to have your client install the SSL cert from the spacewalk server.
Something like `rpm --import http://yourspacewalk.com/pub/rhn-trusted-ssl-cert-1.0-1.noarch.rpm`
That should put an sslCert in `/usr/share/rhn` and when you join your client use `--sslCACert=/usr/share/rhn/RHN-ORG-TRUSTED-SSL-CERT`

Comment: Thanks @spanishgum, I am able to install the cert and fix the certificate error.